# Which is faster in JavaScript, JSON or SOAP parsing?

Tags: javascript, json, wcf, xpath

Here's the two scenarios.

1. We are using a manually built xml soap request with xmlhttprequest, sending it to a wcf soap service, getting back the response and using xPath to parse the data and fill out a drop down list.
2. We are sending a json request to a rest wcf service and getting a json response back and assigning the values to a drop down list

Which scenario is faster? My sense tells me #2 but I could be wrong.

Comment: I would expect option 2 to be faster, but why don't you measure instead of guessing?

Comment: I would bet on JSON to be faster; neither format is hard to parse but there's just so much more "weight" with XML and building a DOM than there is with just plain JavaScript objects. That's just a hunch however.

Comment: Depend of what library you will use to parse each. I think JSON is more confortable to the developer and best of all, you can use your web application to webservices without extra work

Comment: Here's a benchmark using WCF, from 2008 http://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2008/12/27/performance-comparison-soap-vs-json-wcf-implementation.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [WCF - SOAP or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562233/wcf-soap-or-json)

Comment: So for the guys that said JSON is **obviously faster**, it turns out that in WCF it's actually slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After profiling in my scenario, I found out that JSON is actually much faster as far as processing time within the browser

Comment: Using which JS implementation? And which parsers?

Comment: As expected. Almost every browser vendor has spent most of his time optimizing the Javascript engine and with it its JSON support. When you test this in older browsers you may get other results, but in modern browsers this is expected. +1 for testing.

Answer (score 5):

Json will be faster, since Json is essentially Javascript. But that shouldn't be the main motivation. Parsing the data, will assumingly be only a small part of your application anyway.

On the other hand, browsers are also well trained to parse XML.

The main difference is that XML, and therefor SOAP, is larger to send to the client, so the transfer may be a bigger slowdown than the parsing.

Anyway, if you want to know, you should just test and profile instead of guessing or asking.

Comment: That's not always true, it depends on the serialization/deserialization mechanism. WCF, used by OP, actually used to serialize JSON to an internal XML representation, before delivering it to the client.

Comment: JSON is binary data that meets UTF-8 character encoding requirements. It still needs to be parsed to ensure that the UTF-8 characters are valid JSON before it's converted into JavaScript data. It's syntax resembles JavaScripts literal notations, but it's a stretch to say it's "essentially JavaScript".

Comment: Could be, but that doesn't influence either the transfer or the parsing. By the way, I highly doubt if WCF would first encode the data in JSON and then in XML. It's more likely that an internal data structure could be exported to either JSON or XML.

Comment: @graystateiscoming Javascript code itself must be checked for encoding too before it's parsed. A piece of JSON can be put through the parser in the same way as an UTF-8 encoded Javascript snippet.

Comment: While the native JSON parsers will certainly be faster than a JavaScript based parser, you can't just assume that JSON can be treated in the same way as a JavaScript snippet. There are more strict requirements on JSON syntax that must be observed, and there are characters allowed in JSON that would be invalid in a JavaScript program.

Comment: ...but anyway +1 for your last sentence if nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

Option two would generally be faster than option one, as JSON is a much simpler format than XML.

However, if you really need the parsing to be fast, you shouldn't use either, you should use a custom format that is really fast to parse using simple string operations. For example a comma separated string that could be parsed with a `split(',')`.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Comment: Nonsense. Both JSON and XML can be parsed using built in browser functions that can be highly optimized. You shouldn't try to write your own parser in Javascript in a feeble attempt to improve that speed. Besides, communication should be done using a generic and forgiving format. Both XML and JSON are designed for the very purpose of communication and should be preferred over some custom format.

Comment: That's why. Sorry it took a few seconds to write, but if I don't explain in detail why I think it's wrong, you may not want to improve the answer.

Comment: @GolezTrol: What is it that doesn't make sense to you? The OP asked for speed, and if you want that you have to sacrifice other aspects of the communication that could be nice to have, but costs performance.

Comment: +1 I think it's a pretty safe bet that a format designed specific to a given problem will very likely be quicker than using a generalized format like JSON. Certainly a valid option to consider.

Comment: OP asked for a comparison of two generic notations. That aside: If the performance is so much better, you could always consider it, but I think it is unwise to sacrifice the flexibility of such a format for a little speed gain, if any. The parsing should only be a very small percentage of the total calculation time, if any. Modifying the DOM and re-rendering the page are much, much more time consuming. If you really should consider speed optimizations like this, then Javascript may not be the right tool in the first place.

Comment: @GolezTrol: (Reposting, as it got removed in the mess) I woudn't say that it's unwise, as it might be what's needed to get the wanted performance. I just wanted to show that there are other options than the two proposed methods, and that neither of the two is specifically intended for performance.